# Drawing an annotation arrow in a non-equal axes

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

Here is an MCVE of my problem:

```
ax = axes('XLim',[0 20],'YLim',[0 10]);
arrStart = [5 5];
arrLength = 3;
arrDir = pi/4:pi/3:2*pi;
arrEnd = [cos(arrDir)*arrLength+arrStart(1)
          sin(arrDir)*arrLength+arrStart(2)];
for k = 1:size(arrEnd,2)
    arr = annotation('arrow',...
        'X',[arrStart(1) arrEnd(1,k)],...
        'Y',[arrStart(2) arrEnd(2,k)]);
    arr.Parent = ax;
end
```

The code above creates the following figure:

[image: arrows]

You can easily see that none of the arrowheads is aligned correctly with its tail. After some research of this problem, I found that the reason it the different length of the axes (X is twice longer than Y). So if I set both axes to the same limits the problem disappears:

[image: arrows-2]

But in the figure I'm making, which is much more complicated than this example, I need the axes in to have different limits.

Any ideas how to solve this?

p.s: using 'normalized' units I don't see this problem, but setting the correct location for the arrows is cumbersome...

I'm using MatLab R2017a.

Comment: There are many arrow drawing functions on the File Exchange. Some of them are really good. These will take aspect ratio into account.

Comment: Thanks. I know about these functions but I usually prefer to use native Matlab, with no FX files, to avoid possible issues (bug or other incompatibilities).

Comment: This looks like a bug to me, you should report it to MathWorks and use one of the alternatives on File Exchange until it has been fixed.

Comment: Or maybe changing the render mode helps?

Answer (score 1):

Annotation works on figures, uipanels or uitabs, not on axes. Changing the parent to the axes is probably not within expected use of the function. I'd use one of the alternatives on File Exchange as suggested in the comments to create arrows within the axes.

Alternatively, you could use the `quiver` function (but it's probably not recommended either):

```
figure;
ax = axes('XLim',[0 20],'YLim',[0 10]);
arrStart = [5 5];
arrLength = 3;
arrDir = pi/4:pi/3:2*pi;
arrEnd = [cos(arrDir)*arrLength+arrStart(1)
          sin(arrDir)*arrLength+arrStart(2)];
hold on;
for k = 1:size(arrEnd,2)
  quiver(arrStart(1), arrStart(2), arrEnd(1,k)-arrStart(1), arrEnd(2,k)-arrStart(2), 'Color', 'k', 'MaxHeadSize', 0.5, 'Autoscale', 'off');
end
```

[image: arrows plotted using quiver]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Actually one of my first workarounds was to try `quiver` but this gives you minimal control on the arrow style. As for changing the parent of an annotation, this practice is [suggested by Mathworks for placing annotations behind other elements in the figure](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_guis/layout-a-gui-programmatically.html#bue41wp)